# Password protect a PDF file with AES 256

Tags: encryption, pdf, utilities, opensource-projects

I can't find a free/open-source software that password protects my PDFs with AES 256.

`pdftk` just offers 128-bit strength.. In fact I didn't find any other tool that encrypts PDFs.

What tool may I use to password protect my PDFs, using AES 256

Comment: Why not use pgp or openssl or other?

Comment: Because I require a password protected PDF, using AES 256

Comment: You mean, because you need it to be compatible with Acrobat? Because you haven't specified that as a requirement.

Comment: No, simply because I need a password protected PDF, as stated in the OP. I will be using these PDFs for encryption test and other similar projects..

Comment: I understand what you want. I'm just trying to point out that a pdf encrypted with another utility would still be a password protected pdf. Just not the kind you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I understand that this won't offer reasonable encryption for my documents.

Comment: Why do you want AES-256? AES-128 is just as secure.

Comment: It was for a specific case, where AES256 was required. QPDF did the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QPDF says it supports 256bit encryption in it's massive manual. I didn't read it all and have never tried it. It looks like it's worth a shot.

http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Just tried it out, works a treat!